# Converter XML2TEX - Python

Tags: python, xml, converters

I have to write a program, an XML2TEX converter, to pass the course, but there is a problem because I keep getting the following errors:

Here is the code below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def convert_xml_to_latex(xml_file, tex_file):
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    latex_code = ''

    def xml_to_latex(element, level=0):
        nonlocal latex_code
        if element.tag in ['PLANT', 'FOOD', 'BOOK']:
            latex_code += ('\\sub' * level) + 'section' + '{' + element.tag.capitalize() + '}\n'
            for child in element:
                if child.tag not in ['CATALOG']:
                    if child.tag == 'DESCRIPTION':
                        latex_code += '\\textbf{' + child.tag.capitalize() + '}: ' + child.text.strip() + '\\newline\n'
                    else:
                        latex_code += '\\textbf{' + child.tag.capitalize() + '}: ' + child.text + '\\newline\n'
            latex_code += '\\newline\n'

    xml_to_latex(root)

    with open(tex_file, 'w') as tex:
        tex.write(latex_code)

input_xml_file = 'SampleTest.xml'
output_tex_file = 'output.tex'

convert_xml_to_latex(input_xml_file, output_tex_file)
```

I've tried everything, but I'm completely out of ideas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHcIp.png)

Comment: Please add error as a text. Also add `SampleTest.xml` data

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FCKZJQVG

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FCKZJQVG doesn't give me any errors

Comment: Could you give me the code, because it really doesn't work for me, I have no idea what's going on

Comment: I get no error message with your code, but an empty tex file, because your latex_code is empty.

Comment: Can I ask for help, how should I do it to convert the content from xml to tex?

Comment: You post an error message, I assume this comes from encoding of your xml file. Use Notepad++ or PSPad editor and check the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You could first convert `xml` to `dict` and then iterate through `dict` items and convert them to `LaTeX` format:

```
import xmltodict


def convert_xml_to_latex(xml_file, tex_file):
    with open(xml_file, 'r') as f:
        xml = f.read()
    latex = '\\documentclass{article}\n\\begin{document}\n'
    for section, items in xmltodict.parse(xml)['CATALOG'].items():
        latex += '\\section{' + section + '}\n\\begin{enumerate}\n'
        for item in items:
            latex += f'\\item {list(item.values())[0]}\n'
        latex += '\\end{enumerate}\n'
    latex += '\\end{document}'
    with open(tex_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(latex)


convert_xml_to_latex('SampleTest.xml', 'output.tex')
```

LaTeX document:

[image: LaTeX]